# remove specific href children jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code looks something like that:

```
<a href="//index.php?eID=tx_cms_......">
    <img width="1600" height="400" border="0" alt="" src="/link/to/my.jpg">
</a>
```

For some reason, I can't figure out how to get rid of the href-elements, if this special href occurs.

I tried the following:

```
$(".w-slide a[href='//index.php?eID=']").children('img').unwrap();
```

didn't do it.

Also I tried this:

```
$('w-slide a').each(function()
   {
       if ($(this).attr('href').contains('/eID=tx_cms/'))
           {
               $(this).children('img').unwrap();
           }
   }
});
```

What am I missing? I want to keep the image-tags, but unwrap them, so there are no a tags surrounding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your url [start's with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) specific string, not to be equal to it:

```
$(".w-slide a[href^='//index.php?eID=']").children('img').unwrap();
                  ^
```

by using `^` sign your selector will search for elements that have attribute with values that starts with `//index.php?eID=...`

Comment: Also, it is throwing this error in the console:
...value:null},fb.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ex... for that line

Comment: @DasSaffe error you have provided is syntax error. Check your syntax first.

Comment: there we go. I made a mistake with the `^`. I placed it after the equals sign. It is working. Thank you :) - Will accept your answer ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("a[href*='//index.php?eID=']").children("img").remove();
```

You can test the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomisbjuarez/vsnqennq/).

Answer (score 0):

1) You use w-slide class but there is no such class in example.
2) You want to search href EXACTLY like "//index.php?eID=". To search by part use *= matcher like:

`$(".w-slide[href*='//index.php?eID']")`

Example:
http://codepen.io/alkuzad/pen/xbdEYP